# A group is a bounded subset of another group

Tags: abstract-algebra, metric-spaces

What does it mean when people say that a group is a bounded subset of another group?

I need decide whether $SO_2(\mathbb C)$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$. What definition should I use? What is the "distance" function?

Comment: $SO_2(\mathbb C)$ is certainly closed (as a set of solutions of continuous equations). Thus, it is bounded iff it is compact, for any metric compatible with the standard topology on $\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$.

Comment: @lisyarus What are the definitions of closedness and compactness of a group? What is the definition of that metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take *any* norm on $\mathbb C^{2\times2}$ (for instance $\left\lVert\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right\rVert=\sqrt{\lvert a\rvert^2+\lvert b\rvert^2+\lvert c\rvert^2+\lvert d\rvert^2}$) and use the distance $d(M,N)=\lVert M-N\rVert$.